# Crystal Report for Asp Net Core 2

Tags: crystal-reports, asp.net-core-2.0

Problem: Crystal report is not compatible with my asp net core app.
Question: Is crystal report yet to be supported in asp net core? I already searched crystal report for asp net core but I just saw limited to not relevant results. Suggestions or ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't, least you can do is use SQL Server Reporting services if you have a license, but i would just recommend doing it with pure HTML which is what I'm starting to do because apparently they refuse to integrate any actualy report service with ASP .NET Core.