# How to generate crystal report in .Net Core 3.1 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, crystal-reports, asp.net-core-3.1

I created **Asp.Net Core 3.1 application**, and I tried to **apply crystal report on it**, I installed the (`CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine`) from `NuGet`, but, unfortunately it is **showing me this warning** and it is **not working:** 
`(This package may not be fully compatible with your project)` with warning code `NU1701`, That means it is supported by `.Net Framework` not by `.Net Core`.

> **Is there anyway or any work around to allow crystal report working on Asp.Net Core
> 3.1 Project?**

**Note:** I have more than 200 crystal report created in legacy system and I need to apply crystal report in .Net Core 3.1 for this reason.

I looked many resources and the below is a sample, but without any solution:

- https://answers.sap.com/questions/13054071/is-crystal-report-support-net-core-31.html
- [Crystal Report for Asp Net Core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46891612/crystal-report-for-asp-net-core-2)

Comment: Would it be an option to write a dll or webservice to do the crystal stuff? You would be free not to use Asp-Net Core 3.1

Comment: Actually it is not option because I am using .Net Core workload because it is open source  as I can installed in any hosting machine that allow flexibility hosting, unfortunately I will create windows service rather than workloads.